# How to I read in Array formParams using Javalin's swagger/OpenAPI user interface?

Tags: java, kotlin, swagger, openapi, javalin

The current annotation I'm using is as follows:

```
@OpenApi(
    summary = "Update Camera",
    tags = ["Camera"],
    formParams = [
        OpenApiFormParam(name = "groupIds", type = List::class, required = true)
    ]
)
```

Swagger correctly identifies `groupIds` as being an array parameter, but when I run this line of code

```
fun updateCamera(context: Context) {
    val groupIds = context.formParams("groupIds")
    ...
}
```

I just get a in the form `["GroupId1,GroupId2,GroupId3"]` with one string entry where each input `groupId` is separated by a comma. I would like a list with a separate entry for each input `groupId` as follows `["GroupId1", "GroupId2", "GroupId3"]`.

I could just split the string by commas, but I would prefer not to do this in the case that a groupId is input that contains a comma. How do I ensure that the array has been properly transformed into the correct JSON format?